# Linux printing alternate 2 lines in text file

Tags: bash, shell

I've a large text file with the following lines:

```
(total drops) 0
(bytes output) 111
(total drops) 1
(bytes output) 222
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 333
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 444
(total drops) 5
(bytes output) 555
(total drops) 8
(bytes output) 6666
(total drops) 9
(bytes output) 777
(total drops) 10
(bytes output) 888
(total drops) 20
(bytes output) 999
<<SNIP>>
```

I would like to print (starting from top) 2 lines, skip the next 2 lines and print 2 lines again and so forth... The desire output should be like this:

```
(total drops) 0
(bytes output) 111
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 333
(total drops) 5
(bytes output) 555
(total drops) 9
(bytes output) 777
(total drops) 20
(bytes output) 999
```

I tried all sort of sed/awk but still can't get it right...

Comment: What you want to do sounds like an implementation, not a goal.  what do you actually want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this (awk)

```
 cat test.txt | awk '{if (((NR % 4)==1) || ((NR % 4)==2)) {print}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
awk '((NR+3)%4)<2' file
```

This is a shorthand for

```
awk '(((NR+3)%4)<2){print}' file
```

This works because the modulo function `NR%4` returns the values `0,1,2,3`. We need to shift NR such that `0` and `1` are on the correct spot. Hence we add `3` to `NR`. See the following code:

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk '{print NR, NR%4, (NR+3)%4}'
1 1 0
2 2 1
3 3 2
4 0 3
5 1 0
6 2 1
7 3 2
8 0 3
9 1 0
10 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl also, you can get the required output

```
> cat  skip_lines.txt
(total drops) 0
(bytes output) 111
(total drops) 1
(bytes output) 222
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 333
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 444
(total drops) 5
(bytes output) 555
(total drops) 8
(bytes output) 6666
(total drops) 9
(bytes output) 777
(total drops) 10
(bytes output) 888
(total drops) 20
(bytes output) 999
> perl -ne ' print if $.%4==1 or $.%4==2 ' skip_lines.txt
(total drops) 0
(bytes output) 111
(total drops) 3
(bytes output) 333
(total drops) 5
(bytes output) 555
(total drops) 9
(bytes output) 777
(total drops) 20
(bytes output) 999
>
```